# insert string for missing value

Tags: sed, awk

I've run into some problems with editing a text file I've received due to some missing values in a specific column for some rows. For example, here is what the file looks like (mostly):

```
ID10    dad    prbM    ATGD
ID11    mom    prbF    CDSF
ID12    mom        CGDS
ID13    dad    prbF    FSDD
ID14    mom        FDSF
```

As you can see, sometimes the `prb` is not provided for every entry. I've found that when an entry is not present, there are two tab separations. Is there a way to insert a string between the tabs? For example, something like this:

```
ID10    dad    prbM    ATGD
ID11    mom    prbF    CDSF
ID12    mom    none    CGDS
ID13    dad    prbF    FSDD
ID14    mom    none    FDSF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`, assuming your fields are actually separated by tabs:

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '$3 == ""{$3 = "none"};1' input.txt
```

This:

1. Sets the input field separator to a single tab (`-F '\t'`)
2. Sets the output field separator to a tab (`-v OFS='\t'`)
3. Checks if the third field is empty (`$3 == ""`), and if so, sets it to the string `"none"`
4. And always prints the line (`1`).

Comment: Is there a reason `'BEGIN {OFS = "\t"}` wouldn't work to handle the tabs?

Comment: @stellar01 is it not working?

Comment: @Stephane Can you have a look at [Trap ERR only works once?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35397341/2072269) on SO? Thanks for the edit!

Comment: It worked perfectly!

Comment: @stellar01 the answer, or `BEGIN {OFS="\t"}`? (both should)